# Android XML parsing Result cant display in ListView. Nothing is displayed when i run the app

Tags: android, android-listview, xml-parsing

Please help me to get correct my code I don't Know where I am doing wrong.
here . I want to extract notification data from college website to my android app.
Here is my MainActivity.java

```
 package com.eaohealth.zaidu.xmltest;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ResultsCallBack{
    PlaceholderFragment taskFragment;
    ListView articlesListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            taskFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(taskFragment, "MyFragment").commit();
        } else {
            taskFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");

        }
        taskFragment.startTask();
        articlesListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.articlelistView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results) {
        articlesListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,results));
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        TechCrunchTask downloadTask;
        ResultsCallBack callBack;
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            callBack= (ResultsCallBack) activity;

            if(downloadTask!=null){
                downloadTask.onAttach(callBack);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        public void startTask() {
            if (downloadTask != null) {

                downloadTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                downloadTask = new TechCrunchTask(callBack);
                downloadTask.execute();
            }
        }


     @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();

            callBack=null;
            if(downloadTask!=null){
                downloadTask.onDetach();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class TechCrunchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        ResultsCallBack callBack=null;
        public TechCrunchTask(ResultsCallBack callBack){


            this.callBack=callBack;

        }



       public void  onAttach(ResultsCallBack callBack){

           this.callBack=callBack;
        }

        public void  onDetach(){

            callBack=null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if(callBack!=null){
                callBack.onPreExecute();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String downloadURL = "http://www.amarsinghcollege.ac.in/feed";
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(downloadURL);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                processXML(inputStream);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                L.m(e + "");
            }


            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            L.m(result+ "");
            if(callBack!=null){
                callBack.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> processXML(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
            Element rootElement = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();


            L.m("" + rootElement.getTagName());


            NodeList itemList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
            NodeList itemChildren = null;
            Node currentItem = null;
            Node currentChild = null;

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, String> currentMap = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength(); i++) {
                currentItem = itemList.item(i);
                L.m("" + currentItem.getNodeName());
                itemChildren = currentItem.getChildNodes();
                currentMap = new HashMap<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                    currentChild = itemChildren.item(j);
                    if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                       // L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());

                        currentMap.put("title", currentChild.getTextContent());
                    }
                    if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                         //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());
                        currentMap.put("pubDate", currentChild.getTextContent());
                    }

                    if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        //L.m(currentChild.getTextContent());

                      currentMap.put("description", currentChild.getTextContent());
                    }




                }

                if (currentMap != null && !currentMap.isEmpty()) {

                    results.add(currentMap);
                }


            }
            return results;


        }


    }


    }
    interface ResultsCallBack{
    public void onPreExecute();
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String >> results);
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >> dataSource=new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >> dataSource){
        this.context=context;
        this.dataSource=dataSource;
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dataSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        MyHolder holder = null;
        if(row==null){
            row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
            holder=new MyHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(MyHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String ,String> currentItem =  dataSource.get(position);
        holder.articleTextTitle.setText(currentItem.get("title"));
        holder.articlePublishedDate.setText(currentItem.get("pubDate"));
        holder.articleDescriptionText.setText(currentItem.get("description"));


        return row;
    }
    }

    class MyHolder{
    TextView articleTextTitle;
    TextView articlePublishedDate;
    TextView articleDescriptionText;
    public MyHolder(View view){
        articleTextTitle=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.articleTitleText);
        articlePublishedDate=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.articlePublishedDate);
        articleDescriptionText= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.articleDescriptionText);

    }

    }
```

Activiy_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/articlelistView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anodther XML File custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/articleTitleText"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#444"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/articlePublishedDate"
        android:layout_below="@id/articleTitleText"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description"
        android:id="@+id/articleDescriptionText"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/articlePublishedDate"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#444"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First you have to check the size of dataSource in the MyAdapter.

Comment: How can I do that can you please put the code ?

Comment: Zaid want to make sure that you got values in in the Myadapter class . it is done simply by adding these line to the of the constructor of Myadapter class   System.out.println(dataSource.size());

Comment: logcat
 3389-3389/? I/System.out﹕ 0
nothing is displayed while running app

Comment: Now what I have to do ? System.out.println(dataSource.size()); says zero
     please help Nithinlal